# Stop the execution of an infinite loop in Scala 2.11.4 REPL?

Tags: scala

Ctrl+C worked fine on Scala 2.9. But after update to 2.11.4 this command close whole environment.

How can i terminate infinite loop without exit scala console on last version of Scala?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Check these: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/Eq9p4iwAVuM/esP0jE0idx0J and https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6302 (So you cannot stop it with `Ctrl + C`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you start the infinite loop in a new `Thread` and interrupt it, it might work. Though with a key combination most probably it will not return, till bug [SI-6302](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6302) is not fixed. In the meantime you can vote for fixing the bug (or send a pull request).

An example of wrapping would look like this:

```
{
  val thread = new Thread(new Runnable {
    def run() {
      def loop(): Boolean = loop();
      loop()
    }
  })
  thread.start
  thread
}
```

Later you can `interrupt` or `stop` the infinite loop using this reference.